Postman 419 error in PUT and POST request
In Postman POST and PUT request is not sent by postman it shows 419 error whereas I write right URL in postman and also select json and raw body type here is screenshot my url is also correct but it shows page expired postman error screenshot
postman second img of error
I expected that my problem would be solved when i write the problem in this website

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
